# Test Suite Execution Jubula

Tags: functional-testing, jubula

I've been looking at Jubulas automated functional testing tool and following along with the tutorials, but I've become stuck before I ever even got off the ground with it. The user manual provided with the installation hasn't given any answers and I can't find anything in blogs dedicated to Jubula.

My question: I have my test suite, complete with test cases & steps, all set up and ready to go. I've mapped my objects using the editor. I've started the AUT and connected to it. All I have to do is start the test execution.... I click start.... nothing happens.

The Java application is visible (it's a simple calculator) and I can interact with it. But I don't get any dialogue boxes when I press start, which is what is supposed to happen according to the tutorial.

Has anyone tried Jubula and had this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Two things come to mind.

1. If the "Start Test Suite" button is disabled, then it means you still have some sort of a problem stopping the Test Suite being executed (e.g. missing data or object mapping).
2. If the "Start Test Suite" button is enabled, then it might just be that you need to select a Test Suite to execute from the drop-down menu (opened by clicking on the small arrow next to the green button).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but at least I got a report about the tests failing. After I specified the JRE for the AUT (this setting is only shown if you click on the advanced  or expert button) my tests finally started to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's none of the previous answers. If you get a Failed-test report or your Start Test Suite button is disabled then it's pretty obvious. You can find those mistakes mentioned in documentation/blogs.

BUT! There are two errors which leave no traits; no error messages, nothing in logs.

**1.) If there's a version incompatibility** If you installed Jubula from a standalone installer or from Eclipse marketplace then it will work. But if you put it together for yourself then you cold mix up the components. I have an answer on these issues:

[Jubula doesn´t recognize running AUT after upgrade to 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166572/jubula-doesn%C2%B4t-recognize-running-aut-after-upgrade-to-2-0/26611991#26611991)

**2.) If you mislead your AUT-agent by starting an other .exe** It has exactly the symptoms mentioned in the question. It's happening because the application has the Remote-Control (rc) plugin started in it and the AUT-agent is notified about the start. It tries to identify the process within the AUT-configs listed in the client's (testexec's) database and it misidentifies it.

You can solve this by adding each run-situation as a different AUT-config in your database. It's mostly about location in the filesystem: about where the exec process is launched from. I.e: debug-local (from Eclipse launch-bar), exported-local (for Delta-pack exports), QA-local (if you have PDE in your build) etc.