# Jubula doesn´t recognize running AUT after upgrade to 2.0

Tags: jubula

upgraded Jubula from 1.2 to 2.0 (latest), switched jar-file and run a clean. AUT is a RCP-Application, wich is installed via Java Web Start (Jubula executes a Batch-file).

After the upgrade Jubula starts the AUT -but when workbench is loaded Jubula does not recognize it and the progress "starting aut" continuous.

Thanks for any tips / hints

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things to try when you can no longer test an RCP AUT after an upgrade:

- Ensure the old `org.eclipse.jubula.rc.rcp_[version].jar` in your AUT's plugins directory is replaced with the new version from `[jubula_install_directory]/development/rcp-support.zip`
- Ensure your AUT's `configuration/config.ini` file still references the Jubula remote control plugin: `osgi.bundles=[your AUT's bundles],org.eclipse.jubula.rc.rcp@start`

More information and more Q&A about this issue can be found on [the Jubula forums](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/208/).

There are also the occasional quirks to look out for. For example, my current AUT shows a splash dialog on startup, and I have to dismiss it before Jubula will connect. When you're running the AUT and Jubula ITE on the same machine, it does tricky things with focus and the AUT connection can get messed up quite easily in my experience.

I've also had times when the AUT name hasn't shown up in the Running AUTs view, but I can still perform object mapping and run test suites with no problems. If everything seems to be set up correctly, it's worth trying a couple of times in case it's just a quirk messing with you.

Comment: The necessity of "org.eclipse.jubula.rc.rcp@start" is entirely new in E4 platform. It won't start the plugin without this and it's easy to forget about adding it.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late but it might help those lost souls who need to migrate to newer versions of Jubula;

Jubula is made up of 3 components:

1.) Eclipse UI-plugin (or testexec.exe)

2.) AUT agent

3.) RC-plugin as the dependency of the AUT (Remote Control)

They are released in bundles:

```
Jubula 6.0 with 1.2 feature
Jubula 8.0 with 2.3 feature (Java 7 only)
```

My experiences with different versions of these:

```
UI-plugin  Agent   RC     Result
1.2        6.0     1.2    Works (of course)
1.2        8.0     1.2    Works
1.2        8.0     2.3    Can't see AUT
2.3        6.0     1.2    Sees AUT but won't do mapping/tests
2.3        6.0     2.3    Can't see AUT
2.3        8.0     1.2    Sees AUT but won't do mapping/tests
2.3        8.0     2.3    Works (of course)
```

The 2.3 Eclipse UI-plugin won't start without using Java 7 JRE.

But Fabian's problem must be this:

The RC also needs Eclipse e4 Platform.
It writes nothing to log files but it won't start if you export/run your application on RCP 3.x platform. Thus you need to migrate your entire app to e4.