# Jubula - Test suite will not map the object possible jar issue?

Tags: java, automation, automated-tests, ui-automation, jubula

I'm using Jubula to run some automation for a large Java project.  The gateway is a launcher that sets all the parameters etc for the project to run.  The gateway is wrapped as a .exe file.  I converted it back to a jar in order to get Jubula working with it, I managed to one time but not all the projects jars were launched from the main project launcher.  If I attempted to use the .exe within the AUT properties, it won't launch at all.  If I convert back to a jar, then I run into an issue of either not being able to object map no matter how much I press CTL+SHIFT+Q or some of the apps don't launch when I use Jubula to automate.  Also I need to create a bat file to launch either the jar or the .exe file in any case.  I can't just launch the jar from settings within AUT properties.

Is this an issue of the .exe wrapper being the culprit and I should just launch everything without the project launcher or are there known issues with object mapping someone can alert me to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it wasn't an issue with Jubula at all. I had a permissions issue somehow with anything Java related.  So I got my machine reimaged and now everything works like a champ.

Answer (score 0):

The .exe should mean no problem. If you can't map it means the RC (Remote Control) .jar is either not present or is not launched. Could you check that?

The less likely possibilities are Firewall blocking the communication between remote client and AUT agent (corporate machines with Windows usually do), or that you're using incompatible versions of RC/AUT agent/Testexec [triple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166572/jubula-doesn%C2%B4t-recognize-running-aut-after-upgrade-to-2-0/26611991#26611991). The latter can only happen if you've updated your Jubula on your machine to newer version.

Comment: hmm.  I didn't think about the firewall blocking.  Let me look into that.

Comment: I checked the firewall and that isn't an issue.  as to the RC are we talking about the AUT agent? If so that's running just fine.  It's when I attempt to "force" running this with admin rights via bat file that then suddenly I can't object map (I thought running as admin might fire off better).  I also have completely uninstall and reinstall Jubula so this is all new basically.

Comment: The RC is not the AUT agent. Check the link in my answer under the word "triple".