# Cannot run SWT application with Jubula

Tags: java, swt, jubula

I'm using Jubula for testing my SWT application. Everything seems to be OK, but when I start AUT nothing happens. I tried with other applications and it works, but my application cannot be run. When I click on "start AUT" the cursor changes as if he is computing, but then nothing happens.

Comment: Could you share us more information: how do you exported your application, what are the other apps you managed to start? Is it a Standalone version or you use it as an Eclipse Plug-in? What version of Jubula? Check out these answers too: [no interaction with AUT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392134/test-suite-execution-jubula), [Upgrade Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166572/jubula-doesn%C2%B4t-recognize-running-aut-after-upgrade-to-2-0)

Comment: I finally succeeded to run my application I'm using a standalone version of jubula , the problem is that I selected SWT instead of RCP .